# gsoap convert anyAttribute to custom type

Tags: c++, xml, wsdl, gsoap

Using gsoap, I have created a client for a soap server.
In wsdl from which I created my sources there is a type with an element of type NotificationMessage as defined in [wsnt](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd).
Is there any way to convert it to a custom object?
I need something like following:

```
/* get response */
_wsnt__NotificationMessageHolderType_Message message = response.Message;
if (message is _tt__Message)
{
    _tt__Message m = message as _tt__Message;
    /* do something with m */
} else if (message is std::string) {
    std::string str = message as std::string;
    /* do something with str */
} else {
    Warning("Unrecognized type");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use wsdl2h option -d? This generates code that adds DOM support (do not use option -x at the same time).

A DOM node graph `xsd__anyType` holds the content of `Message`. The DOM content can be set and read, and may also contain serializable data, as described in [XML DOM and XPath](http://www.genivia.com/doc/dom/html/index.html) for gSOAP.

To enable serialization of C/C++ within an XML DOM, use `SOAP_DOM_NODE`. The XML element tag name should match with the name of a C/C++ type to deserialize it automatically into a C/C++ object.

Because the `_wsnt__NotificationMessageHolderType_Message` class is embedded you cannot give an overriding definition in `typemap.dat` as you can do for globally defined classes (at least not with gSOAP up to 2.8.28).